# I can't get the directory contents to not be listed when viewing localhost/mySite

Tags: apache2, directory, websites

I have localhost/mySite/logs as password protected and it works using .htaccess and .htpasswd, but additionally I would like to have localhost/mySite to not list directory contents. I've tried doing this in /etc/apache2/apache2/apache2.conf:
`<Directory "/www/var/mySite">

Options -Indexes

</Directory>`
Currently I have this in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default:

`<Directory /var/www/>

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

AllowOverride All

Order allow,deny

allow from all

</Directory>`

I can get around this by putting a blank index.html in /var/www/mySite but what is the other way using Options -Indexes? (I got from some where else that by default all files under /var/www ignore the .htaccess file so I changed the AllowOverride **None** to **All** in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default)

Answer (score 1):

My dirty solution is to create an empty index.html file in each such directory.

Comment: This is what I'm using currently, I haven't found a better, _working_ way.

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/apache2/sites-available/default, somewhere there you will hit:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   [...]
</Directory>
```

remove Indexes and I think you solved your problem.

Comment: Override those who want to be seen.

Comment: That did not help. When I did remove "Indexes" and restart apache, I not only got `Forbidden  
You don't have permission to access /mySite/ on this server.` but I also couldn't access to `mySite/logs with the right user name and password, I got the same error.